# Emberjs - Object binding within ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to bind an Ember object to a property in an ArrayController. The properties of this object will be used for all objects added to the ArrayController in calculations.

Here's a simple example of what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/EjDFS/2/

As you can see, the object that I am trying to bind is undefined within the array controller. I do not want to bind this object directly to the objects that are added to the array controller.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its undefined because when it fires, it hasn't completed its run loop.

and as for `App.ObjectOne.param3`, you need to use `this.get('param1')` instead of `param1`, the same with `param2`

http://jsfiddle.net/EjDFS/4/

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, but do you know why the alert occurs twice now? When I switch the observe from '@each' to 'content.@each' it fixes it so it occurs once... do you know what's going on here?

Comment: Because with `@each` it will also fires when the `content` is empty.